# Using javascript to change an embedded SVG in IE9

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to use basic DOM manipulation with Javascript to change the contents of a text-node in an SVG.

Basically this is the SVG I am embedding:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <text>
        <tspan x="100" y="100" fill="#000000" font-size="10">Name:
            <tspan id="firstName">placeholder</tspan>
        </tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

And this is my javascript snippet:

```
document.querySelector('#firstName').innerHTML = 'Test';
```

This works in Chrome. It fails in IE9.

I have tried fetching the SVG as a string with AJAX, creating a `JQuery` element from said string and doing the replacement before adding it to the DOM but that did not work either. IE9 did manage to render it with the placeholder text though, so I suppose I can fall back on using a regexp on the string before creating a DOM element from it, but I'd love to avoid that.

Interestingly enough, I can delete the `tspan` element and IE will remove it. I can also edit the contents of the `tspan` via IE's developer tools and the image gets updated.

I just can't seem to use either `innerHTML` or `JQuery.html()` to update it.

I've created a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/D9SN3/4/) that tries to change an already embedded DOM since that was an easier thing to turn into a fiddle than the `JQuery` approach. The behaviour is the same so I am guessing the underlying problem is the same as well.

If anyone can explain to me why this does not work in IE9 that would be great.

Comment: I tried to look at some kind of JQuery SVG plugin linked from this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3856995/957731
But when the download button fails on a Javascript error because Ghostery is blocking Google Analytics I am thinking I don't want that plugin in my codebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVG is not HTML, that's why `innerHTML` doesn't work. Use `textContent` instead:

```
var text = document.querySelector('#firstName').textContent = 'Test';
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm still exploring various ways of using SVGs and since 'innerHTML' was working in Chrome I assumed there was some kind of problem with re-rendering in IE (heaven knows I've run into other SVG issues with that browser).

Comment: Chrome (Blink actually) implements http://domparsing.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-innerhtml, which makes innerHTML work properly on SVG. Presumably IE hasn't yet implemented that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the workaround, basically manipulation the SVG as a string prior to injecting it into the DOM.

```
var svgStr = ''
    + '<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 200 200">'
    + '  <text>'
    + '    <tspan x="100" y="100" fill="#000000" font-size="10">Name: ##PLACEHOLDER##</tspan>'
    + '  <text>'
    + '</svg>';

svgStr = svgStr.replace('##PLACEHOLDER##', 'Test');
$('body').append(svgStr);
```

(I'm obviously not inlining the SVG in my code, but fetching it as a resource with an AJAX request, however that is kind of irrelevant here so it's omitted).

This works in IE9, as demonstrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/D9SN3/5/).

Any kind of cleaner solution is welcome.