# How to talk to external svg file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have a function that loads an external svg file into my html. The svg loads fine but I'm unable to communicate with the file as in getting elements. Any suggestions?

```
$(function() {
    $('#map-container').load('svg/world-map.svg');
    $('#unitedstates .location').click(function() {
        alert('usa click');
    });
});
```

I'm trying to keep my working file down, that the reason for not having the svg in the same html file as the jquery reference. Is there a way to reference my jquery file in the svg file

Comment: Not sure what you are exactly trying to do to the SVG file, but I found this on Stack : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856937/edit-contents-of-embedded-svg-file-using-javascript

Looks like you have to make the changes while the SVG is loading.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using [jQuery SVG](http://keith-wood.name/svgRef.html). To load the file you can use this:

```
var svg = $('#map-container').svg({loadURL: 'svg/world-map.svg'});
```

As far as I know you can interact with your SVG file like this:

```
var g = svg.getElementById('group1');
//Change some settings:
svg.change(g, {cx: 200, cy: 250});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Snap svg to load svg files and then manipulate them after loading:

http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-load-animate.html

And here in their web site they a getting started page and click on number 15 and you can see how an image is loaded and then part of the image selected and manipulated  :

http://snapsvg.io/start/

I hope it helps!